# Is it possible to extend native ios Mail app to trigger/launch external apps

Tags: ios5

I'd like to know whether it is feasible to develop extensions for the native Mail app that would allow a user to trigger or launch a third-party app.  For example, while viewing a message, I'd like to be able to click the reply/forward icon and see a third-party app registered (such as say iAnnotatePDF) that would allow me to send the message (along with any relevant metadata) to that external app.

If this is possible, I'd be grateful for some direction on how to go about accomplishing this action.

Thanks in advance!

Shaheeb R.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the technique described here](http://www.trendlineinteractive.com/2011/09/launching-ios-apps-from-an-email-newsletter/#axzz1kzj17cUL) to do something like what you want. I'm not sure if it's exactly what you're looking for, as it doesn't register an app with Mail, but it does launch another app.

Comment: Ooh, very close to the right track, but this technique is basically embedding the trigger in a specific message.  What I'm interested in is being able to launch a third-party app from *any* message.  Does that make sense?  Thank you for such a prompt and thoughtful response.